# Verifying that send data is in HTTP (1.0 and 1.1) protocol

Tags: python, http, protocols, network-protocols, http-protocols

I'm trying  to write a server in python 2.7 which receives and verifies that the client uses HTTP protocol (either 1.1 or 1.0 but a support has to be given for both).

How can I verify that the client is sending "a correct" protocol (either 1.0 or 1.1) and not trying to inject code to my server?

Comment: what would be an example of "trying to inject code?"

Comment: ..are you sure you actually need to write *a server*? why are you doing that?

Comment: (btw, the first line of an HTTP request is something like ``GET / HTTP/1.0``, that's how you determine the version the client is trying to use..)

Comment: The bare syntax of the HTTP protocol is fairly simple and uninteresting.  It's the URL parameters and/or the payload, if any, which needs close examination.

Comment: @IfLoop i'm not sure. That was the instruction of my exercise. redShadow, that's an exercise. I asked in our forum and verifying `GET /HTTP/1.0` is insufficient for verifying. Can you expand your last comment please? thanks.

Comment: Use some well tested HTTP-Server - there are many ready-to-use packages for python - then the probability, that someone can inject code via HTTP protocol is very low, and if so, this security hole is hopefully closed quickly.

Comment: The instructions was `You mustn't use httplib`, so I think they won't like it.

Comment: DanisFischer see @Daniel answer, and read carefully that RFC -- this is the right path if you need to implement the protocol. (BTW, for the future, it's good practice to indicate in the answer that this is for some "homework".. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read and implement [rfc-2616](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2616.txt) carefully. This is the reference for HTTP-1.1. If you don't use `eval` or call any external programs, to probability, that someone can inject code is very low.